# ActionBar add spacing between components

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add some spacing between the actionbar's back navigation button, icon and title. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int actionbarTitleId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/action_bar_title", null, null); //TextView hosted in LinearLayout
int upImageViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/up", null, null);//ImageView hosted in LinearLayout or HomeView
int homeId = android.R.id.home; //ImageView hosted in HomeView
```

Use `findViewById` with each of the ids to get `View` (or appropriate cast) for each.

Try not to modify the `LayoutParams`. But add padding between them or just use existing `LayoutParams` to modify the margins.